Jest test code fails with navigation and jest function
This is the React code
import type { FC } from 'react';
import React from 'react';
import styles from './LeaveConfirmModal.module.css';
import { Button, Modal } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { LEAVE_ORGANIZATION } from 'GraphQl/Mutations/OrganizationMutations';
import { USER_ORGANIZATION_CONNECTION } from 'GraphQl/Queries/OrganizationQueries';
import { useMutation } from '@apollo/client';
import { toast } from 'react-toastify';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

interface InterfaceLeaveConfirmModalProps {
  show: boolean;
  onHide: () => void;
  orgId: string;
}

/**
 * LeaveConfirmModal component for user to leave an organization.
 *
 * Provides:
 * - Modal to confirm leaving an organization.
 *
 * @param orgId - ID of the current organization.
 * @param show - Boolean indicating if the modal should be shown.
 * @param onHide - Function to hide the modal.
 *
 * @returns JSX.Element - The rendered LeaveConfirmModal component.
 */

const LeaveConfirmModal: FC<InterfaceLeaveConfirmModalProps> = ({
  onHide,
  show,
  orgId,
}) => {
  const { t: tCommon } = useTranslation('common');
  const { t } = useTranslation('translation', {
    keyPrefix: 'orgLeave',
  });
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const [leaveOrganization] = useMutation(LEAVE_ORGANIZATION, {
    refetchQueries: [
      { query: USER_ORGANIZATION_CONNECTION, variables: { id: orgId } },
    ],
  });

  async function leaveOrg(): Promise<void> {
    try {
      await leaveOrganization({
        variables: {
          organizationId: orgId,
        },
      });
      onHide();
      navigate('/user/organizations');
    } catch (error: unknown) {
      if (error instanceof Error) {
        toast.error(t('errorOccured'));
      }
      onHide();
    }
  }
  return (
    <Modal
      show={show}
      onHide={onHide}
      size="lg"
      aria-labelledby="leave-confirm-modal"
      centered
    >
      <Modal.Header closeButton>
        <Modal.Title>{t('heading')}</Modal.Title>
      </Modal.Header>
      <Modal.Body>
        <h4>{t('confirmation')}</h4>
        <p>{t('description')}</p>
      </Modal.Body>
      <Modal.Footer className={styles.leaveConfirmModalFooter}>
        <Button variant="danger" onClick={onHide}>
          {tCommon('cancel')}
        </Button>
        <Button
          data-testid="leave-confirm-modal-confirm-btn"
          onClick={leaveOrg}
        >
          {tCommon('confirm')}
        </Button>
      </Modal.Footer>
    </Modal>
  );
};

export default LeaveConfirmModal;

And the corresponding jest code
import React from 'react';
import {
  render,
  screen,
  fireEvent,
  waitFor,
  RenderResult,
  act,
} from '@testing-library/react';
import LeaveConfirmModal from './LeaveConfirmModal';
import { MockedProvider } from '@apollo/client/testing';
import { LEAVE_ORGANIZATION } from 'GraphQl/Mutations/OrganizationMutations';
import { toast } from 'react-toastify';
import i18n from 'utils/i18nForTest';
import { I18nextProvider } from 'react-i18next';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

jest.mock('react-toastify', () => ({
  toast: {
    success: jest.fn(),
    error: jest.fn(),
  },
}));

async function wait(ms = 100): Promise<void> {
  await act(() => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(resolve, ms);
    });
  });
}

const mockNavigate = jest.fn();

jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('react-router-dom'),
  useNavigate: () => mockNavigate,
}));

const translations = {
  ...JSON.parse(
    JSON.stringify(i18n.getDataByLanguage('en')?.translation.orgLeave ?? {}),
  ),
  ...JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(i18n.getDataByLanguage('en')?.common ?? {})),
  ...JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(i18n.getDataByLanguage('en')?.errors ?? {})),
};

const renderLeaveConfirmModal = (
  onHide: () => void,
  mocks: any,
): RenderResult => {
  return render(
    <MockedProvider mocks={mocks} addTypename={false}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <I18nextProvider i18n={i18n}>
          <LeaveConfirmModal
            show={true}
            onHide={onHide}
            orgId="6437904485008f171cf29924"
          />
        </I18nextProvider>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </MockedProvider>,
  );
};

const mocks = [
  {
    request: {
      query: LEAVE_ORGANIZATION,
      variables: { organizationId: '6437904485008f171cf29924' },
    },
    result: {
      data: {
        leaveOrganization: true,
      },
    },
  },
];

describe('LeaveConfirmModal', () => {
  const onHide = jest.fn();

  it('calls leaveOrganization mutation and handles success', async () => {
    const { debug } = renderLeaveConfirmModal(onHide, mocks);

    const confirmButton = screen.getByTestId('leave-confirm-modal-confirm-btn');

    fireEvent.click(confirmButton);

    await wait();

    await waitFor(() => {
      debug();
      expect(onHide).toHaveBeenCalled();
      expect(mockNavigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/user/organizations');

    });
  });
});

I want to write complete test when the leaveorganization mutation is called and it is succeeded. But when I run the test file I am getting an error of

LeaveConfirmModal › calls leaveOrganization mutation and handles success
    expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...expected)
    Expected: "/user/organizations"
    Number of calls: 0


My aim is to cover the lines of code in test which are written in the react component when the leaveOrganization is succeeded.
